# How to create amazon api gateway to be private

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a bunch of AWS Lambda functions that are hooked into the Amazon API Gateway and take in JSON via an https:// endpoint.  How do I make the API private for my app and my cognitoId?

Comment: Hi, how is this not a duplicate of your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38890643/creating-a-private-amazon-api-gateway

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom authorizer, which is a Lambda function that inspects the execution context/cognito credentials:

https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3JK25U7Z9EUIU/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-User-Pools-with-API-Gateway

If your API is mobile-only, you could instead call directly into your Lambdas using the AWS iOS SDK.  Then you could manage the Lambda execution via IAM permissions.